# How to get blogger profile picture original size url

Tags: html, image, widget, blogger

### How to get blogger profile picture original URL(high resolution) ?

`data:photo.url`  gives me thumbnail img of profile pic URL

http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-kOaDP1swqMA/U8dT4DlH3mI/AAAAAAAAANk/wh1alF0NIeY/s80/geek%255B1%255D.jpg

And I don't want to hard code to this

http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-kOaDP1swqMA/U8dT4DlH3mI/AAAAAAAAANk/wh1alF0NIeY/

Is there way to get original img url, without doing URL manipulation ?

**Now I have :**

```
<div id='profile-line'>
<b:section id='round_logo' maxwidgets='1' showaddelement='no'>
  <b:widget id='my' locked='false' title='About Me' type='Profile'>
    <b:includable id='main'>
    <img expr:src='data:photo.url' expr:width='data:photo.width' id='profile'/>
</b:includable>
  </b:widget>
</b:section>
</div>
```

It gives me tiny thumb 77*80 :(

Comment: What is `data:photo.url` pulling? I have a related issue.

Comment: @KenSharp it's related to blogger Profile Widget and give blogger profile picture url read this : https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/47270?hl=en#profile

Comment: Ah, that's excellent, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `data:post.authorImage` inside the post includable.